# Angular nvd3 not showing

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

I am trying to display a real-time line-graph using angular.js nvd3 [1].  It should plot altitude vs. time.

The problem I am having is with getting the x-axis to show the time data array correctly.  This is what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JuXr.png

and this is the data that I am trying to show:

```
$scope.chart1data = [
      {
          "key": "Altitude",
          "values": [{x:"2013-03-04_12:00:00",y:50},{x:'2013-03-04_13:00:00',y:1000}]
      }
  ];
```

chart options:

```
$scope.chart1options = {
      chart: {
          type: 'lineChart',
          height: 350,
          x: function(d){ return d.x; },
          y: function(d){ return d.y; },
          useInteractiveGuideline: true,
          dispatch: {
              stateChange: function(e){ console.log("stateChange"); },
              changeState: function(e){ console.log("changeState"); },
              tooltipShow: function(e){ console.log("tooltipShow"); },
              tooltipHide: function(e){ console.log("tooltipHide"); }
          },
          xAxis: {
              axisLabel: 'Time',
              tickformat: function(d) {
                  return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')(new Date(d))
              }
          },
          yAxis: {
              axisLabel: 'Altitude (m)',
              tickFormat: function(d){
                  return d3.format('.02f')(d);
              },
              axisLabelDistance: 100
          }
      }
  };
```

If anyone knows how to get the x axis to show month/date-hour:minute for each data point, and have it scaled by time I could really use some help!

[1] http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart

Comment: Because x axis have string values, you should parse it to date format: `x: function(d){ return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S').parse(d.x); }`. Check [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/a4NZMU?p=preview).

Comment: Awesome, that worked thanks!  Nice library btw.